# How can I use @Bean in super abstract classes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to declare `@Bean` in a super `abstract class` to prevent declaring it for each subclass.

Consider this class hierarchy:

```java
@Configuration
public class Config {
  public static abstract class A {
    @Bean
    public myBean() {
      return new MyBean();
    }
  }
  public static class B extends A {
    // Some stuff here
  }
  public static class C extends A {
    // Some other stuff here
  }
}
```

I can't do this in Spring Boot 1.5.9 (Spring Framework 4.3.13).

It throws:

`org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate foo.bar.A: Is it an abstract class?`

Is there a way to prevent duplicating `@Bean` for each subclass?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48440669/how-to-create-bean-using-bean-in-spring-boot-for-abstract-class

Comment: Maybe if you move `A` to it's own file. Spring should normally not try to instantiate `A` unless it's explicitly marked as `@Configuration` or `@Component`.

Comment: **You cannot create Beans of abstract class**

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your problem is not duplicate beans. The problem is that 
`class A` is not annotated with `@Configuration`. If you add it, it will start without a problem.

**The following is the specs for configuration classes.** [The Spring's @Configuration documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) states -

- Configuration classes must be provided as classes (i.e. not as instances returned from factory methods), allowing for runtime enhancements through a generated subclass.
- Configuration classes must be non-final.
- Configuration classes must be non-local (i.e. may not be declared within a method).
- Any nested configuration classes must be declared as static.
- @Bean methods may not in turn create further configuration classes (any such instances will be treated as regular beans, with their configuration annotations remaining undetected).

---

**About that duplicated Beans**

Only single Bean will be created. The bean definition will only be loaded and created once :)

---